# Non-Externalized strings : How to ignore empty strings?

Tags: java, android

I'm rather new in Java / Android programming. Here my problem : I turned on the "Non-Externalized string literal" checking at compile time to prepare my app to be internationalized. Everything works fine except that i'd like to ignore empty strings... By example, i often use ProgressDialog spinner this way (which always display a warning) :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyClass.this, "", getString(R.string.msg_wait));
```

I had not to the problem in C# as I could use string.Empty constant, but I think it does not exist in Java. Should I declare my own static constant EMPTY_STRING ?

Edit : I know that there is a //$NON-NLS... directive, I just want to know if a can *automatically* ignore empty strings

Comment: There is `StringUtils.EMPTY` in apache commons.

Comment: I don't know enough about android to help with 3rd-party library support there.

Comment: Are you sure the empty String is what triggers the warning? There is also "Please wait"

Comment: Yes, I just picked a non externalized string in my code. I'll correct the code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare a variable `EMPTY_STRING`, so you'd only have to add the directive once. I'm not aware of one existing in the Android libraries.

```
//$NON-NLS... etc.
public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
```

Perhaps you can even fool the checking by doing `EMPTY_STRING = new String(new char[0]);` or something. Although I doubt that really benefits you at all - nothing wrong with a single directive (particularly if well commented above).

---

Apache [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has [`StringUtils.EMPTY`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#EMPTY), which would also suffice. AFAIK, [this library can be used in Android](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/apache_lang/apache-commons-lang) and offers a wide range of helpful things "missing" from the normal libraries. Hopefully you can find other benefits to obtain from it!

Answer (score 0):

If your not displaying a title, you should simply pass `null` for the `title` parameter to the `ProgressDialog.show()` function, like this:

```
 ProgressDialog.show(context, null, message);
```